# Facebook API: How to delete photos from Coverimage Album?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm looking for a way to remove images in the Cover-Image album.

To post/change a cover via Facebook API we need to upload the photo into the profile - so that we get the Facebook PhotoID. 
After that we are able to change the Cover by sending the PhotoID of the uploaded Photo.

So in my case i automatically change, for example, the cover image every hour. 
The image file is autogenerated and just change a few things in the image.

So there are a few images daily in the cover folder which i don't know how to delete.

Just make an api call with the photoid and "delete" params don't work.

I get the following response on call /[photoid]/?[token]&method=delete

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) App can only delete photos created by the same app",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

It's because Facebook create a copy of the uploaded Photo and adding this to Cover-Image folder.

Does anybody know another way?

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: Give it a work around?

Comment: If there was a workaround it would be possible